# How to find places to add power indicator light in simple DC circuits?

Tags: led, power, dc

I build a lot of little hobby circuits and I usually place them inside of some kind of project box. Right now I'm working on the "Atari Punk Consol" by Forrest Mimms. It looks like this:

[image]

I tried adding an LED to this circuit coming in from the voltage source but that had some detrimental effects on the sounds that this thing produces.

I like to add power indicator LEDs but I'm not skilled yet at circuit design. I realize every circuit is different, so I'm not asking about where to put it on this circuit specifically, but can someone give me some guidance on how to find good places in my circuits to add a power indicator light? What should I look for and what additional components would I need? Any information pointing me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why an LED + resistor from +9V to ground would have any effect on this circuit's output. You did remember the resistor didn't you ... ?

Comment: standard 5mm LED with 1k ohm resistor yes... works (kinda) but severely diminishes the output volume.

Comment: If it's affecting the output volume then your 9V battery is probably going flat.

Comment: if theres only 1 input power source, then the easiest is to use a LED and resistor as the others have said. If there is a logic power supply and some other power supply you want to monitor, you can use a simple op-amp as a comparator to sense if the other input voltage is above a certain value, like 2V or whatever.

Comment: another thing you can do is use a BJT transistor rather than an op-amp, to monitor the input line, but it's just as much circuitry to set that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "power on" light would normally be connected between the positive supply (after the power switch, if any) and ground.

If you use an LED for the light, you must connect a resistor in series with the LED.  The resistor value is not critical, but if your device is powereed by a battery, you probably want to minimize the power consumed by the light.  You might start with a 1.5 K (1500 Ohm) resistor - a higher value will reduce the current, and dim the LED...

Comment: Oh okay, thanks... I had a bad resistor somehow but I've caught it and got it fixed now. It's working like a charm. Thanks for your help.